# GIS plugin in Django is throwing openssl error. undefined symbol: EVP_md2

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am trying to use the Geodjango plugin django.contrib.gis for my project. But as soon as I add it to the INSTALLED_APPS I am getting the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/options.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 50, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: EVP_md2, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
```

I am using redhat linux version 8.